# Can you curve or round just the top corners of a box in html?

Tags: html, css

Please is there a code to round just the top corners of a div? I'm trying to create a card, and here is the code so far:

```
<div id="card1">
            <div id="card1i"></div>
           
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#card1 {
border-radius: 2%;
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);
  }
```

In the card, I want to add a title, which would have a different background, so I added this:

```
#card1i {
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
background-color: rgb(212, 202, 202);
  }
```

But adding the second div (card1i) for the title removes the slightly round top corners of the original card (card1). If I try to add border radius to the second div (card1i), which is the title with a different background colour, the bottom corners also would become round, which I don't want. Please is the a way to make just the top corners of the second div round, or is there a totally different way of doing this card?

Comment: use this: `border-radius{10px,10px, 0 ,0}`

Comment: do better in pixels for two containers. - `border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 20px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use border-top-right-radius and border-top-left-radius. Explore on border radius in w3schools, you can get lot of other css properties to make use of.